# using $.post method twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

is it possible to use jquery.post for 2 level what i mean is (the secod $.post depends on the first one )

let's assume that a company have a phone number, name and description (for the sake of this example)

```
<body>

    // retrieving companies that have a name similar (or contains )
    // what is written in the input box bellow :

    <form method="POST" id="searchForm">
       <input type="text" name ="name" id="name">
       <input type="submit" value="Find">
    </form>

    // when the user enter a name in the input and submit the form
    // with out refreshing the page (adding return false to the jquery click function) 
    // we will display all retrieved company code inside <ul>(using loop for example)

    <ul id="companies_list">

      <li id="company"><input type="hidden" value="[company code goes here ]>
      <span>[company name goes here]</span><li>
    </ul>

        // the user select  the desired company name (li item )
        // and then without refreshing the page we will display the information
       // about the selected company in the company_details area

    <div id="company_details">
         [here goes the selected company details]
    </div>
```

jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// when the dom is ready start manipulating 
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event){
 // stop form from being submited normaly
  event.preventDefault();

// sendig post data
var name = $("input[type="text"]").val();
 var url = "ajax/search.php";
 var posting = $.post( url, {name:name} );

posting.done(function(data) {
  // assuming the data holds companies list (ie: <li>c1</li><li>c2</li>)
  $("#companies_list").html(data);  
});


});



// the last part (below)  does'not work for me

$("#company").click(function(){
    var code = [ company code stored in hidden field]
    var url = 'ajax/detail';
    var posting1 = $.post(url,{code:code});
    posting1.done(function(data){
      put the result in the company_details div
      $("#company_details").html(data)
    });
    return false;
});

});
```

Comment: Yes. If the second AJAX call needs to wait until the first has completed, make the second call in the `done` handler of the first.

Comment: Oh, wait, this is just an event delegation problem (made worse by invalid HTML). The fact that the `$('#company').click()` also uses an AJAX request is irrelevant.

Comment: Rather than replacing the HTML of companies_list (which invalidates the clickhandler assigned to #company by rewriting that element, and forcing you to use a promise or other such messy constructs) why not simply replace the company name and id values in your first ajax handler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the third argument to `$.post` is function that is executed when post successfuly completes. So the code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// when the dom is ready start manipulating 
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event){
 // stop form from being submited normaly
  event.preventDefault();

// sendig post data
var name = $("input[type="text"]").val();
 var url = "ajax/search.php";
 var posting = $.post( url, {name:name}, function(data) {
  // assuming the data holds companies list (ie: <li>c1</li><li>c2</li>)
  $("#companies_list").html(data);  
} )
});
```

Comment: That's functionally equivalent to what they already have using `.done()`, and doesn't answer the question at all.